# String variable just refuses to be turned into an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am writing a python GUI application which takes an entry from the user, converts it into an integer, and then uses that integer with the datetime module. However I have run into a problem which hopefully you can help with.

I am using Tkinter to construct a GUI with 3 elements, an entry box, a "GO!" button, and a "quit" button. Here is my simplified code:

```
class MyFirstGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):

        numberdate = StringVar()

        Label(root,text="Enter the Number of days you would like to search in").grid(row=0)
        self.a = Entry(root,textvariable=numberdate )
        self.a.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.close_button = Button(master, text="Close", command=master.quit)
            self.close_button.grid(row=3, column=1)

        self.macro_button = Button(master, text="GO!", command=self.macro)
            self.macro_button.grid(row=4, column=1)
```

Now this seems simple enough, I know I have saved the variable as a StringVar but I will address that later. Now when the "GO!" button is pressed, it executes another portion of code, this is as follows:

```
numberdate = self.a.get() 

int(numberdate)

date_threshold = datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=numberdate)
```

However whenever I run this code, python throws the following error at me:

```
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: str
```

Now obviously this means the variable numberdate hasn't been converted into an integer, it is still a number, but for the life of me I can't work out why.

I've tried saving the variable as an IntVar in the first half of the code, but still no luck.

Is there an obvious mistake in my code that I am missing, or am I just going mad?

Comment: if you are using `self.a.get`, why do you use `textvariable`? Are you aware that `textvariable` is optional, and usually completely unnecessary?

Comment: @bryanoakley, hi there, no I wasn't unfortunately, I copied my tkinter code from an app I had written before and failed to notice, my mistake!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The conversion happens, but nobody was listening.  You have to rebind the name to the return value:

```
numberdate = int(numberdate)
```

Comment: I'm an idiot, works perfectly. Its 6:30 where I am after a long day if that makes it any more excusable. Thanks again! @wim

Comment: That did peak my curiosity then, why didn't it work then when I defined 'numberdate' as an IntVar at the beginning? @wim

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.  I don't have much familiarity with tkinter.